# Use routeParams to create templateUrl in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use the route parameters as part of the route?

E.g.

```
when('/static/:dynamic', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/static/:dynamic.html',
    controller: 'staticController'
})
```

I don't need a dynamic controller. I only need that the URL is resolved dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a proper solution.

You can put a function into the templateUrl:

```
when('/static/:dynamic', {
    templateUrl: function(urlattr){
        return urlattr.dynamic + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'staticController'
})
```

Its also possible to put a * into the route, which allows you to get the whole path as one string:

```
when('/:dynamic*', {
    templateUrl: function(urlattr){
        return urlattr.dynamic + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'staticController'
})
```

With that solution you can use "localhost:13370/app/index.html#/static/dynamic/random" as URL and get "static/dynamic/random" as string in urlattr.dynamic.